# Using Jetpack Compose State delegate syntax with data class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I really like using the `by` delegate with [Compose State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state) as it hides the boiler plate of having "reactive" data ie:

```
val message: String by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

message = "No boilerplate"
```

When using props this way, unidirectional data flow (or props down, events up) is clean and easy.

However when wanting to group data together in a `data class`, or observe a view model prop as state (ie: using `observeAsAState()`) I have to declare the prop of type `State` eg:

```kotlin
data class MyUiProps(
  val message: State<String>
)

/*
 * Different ways of creating instances of `MyUiProps`.
 * 
 * In the examples the result is of type `State` rather than
 * `String` like using the `by` delegate
 *
 */
var props = MyUiProps(viewModel.message.observesAsState(""))
props = MyUiProps(remember { mutableStateOf("") })

props.message.value = "Urgh boilerplate"
```

Is there a way to still use the `by` delegate with a data class like the following pseudo code

```
data class MyUiProps(
  val message: String
)

val props = MyUiProps(
  message = by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
)

props.message = "Yay no boilerplate"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `MyUiProps` as the state you are exposing in ViewModel. Exposing single fields is tedious and unreadable.

If you have something like this in ViewModel:

```
// Expose whole state in ViewModel
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(MyUiProps()) // this will set default values in the model
val state: StateFlow<MyUiProps> = _state // observe this as state in compose

// inside ViewModel if you want to update the state
_state.value = _state.value.copy(fieldYouWantToUpdate = newValue)

// in composable
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
```

Comment: That works for simple apps/examples. But in complex applications, cluttering your view model with data structures that are coupled to a particular UI control/Composable leads to problems. Components/Composables should be as self contained as possible, defining the data the need and the events they emit. The view model can adapt data to required and respond to events from Composables.

Comment: @kierans i do agree with that, but i do not understand how this is coupling here. ViewModel defines state of the screen, compose is rendering UI based on that state. My standard practise is to collectAsState at the top composable and then pass parameters that are needed in more specialised composables

Comment: `ViewModel` holds state that the UI uses, but does not own. It shouldn't hold UI state. For example, `ViewModel` holds the customer Profile. It shouldn't hold state as to whether a button is enabled or not.

My "Props" concept (which I flogged from Vue) is the mapping of `ViewModel` state into Component/Composable specific state. So it's not appropriate to store an instance in `ViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `by` inside a constructor. Still, you don't need the so-called "boilerplate" that you are showing. This is how you do it:

```
data class MyUiProps(
    var message: MutableState<String>
) {

}

val props = MyUiProps(
    message = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
)

props.message.value = "Yay no boilerplate"
```

You need to be using `MutableState` and not just `State` in your data classes parameter. This avoids the need to use `observeAsState`

Comment: Thanks @Johann. I edited my example to clarify what I was trying to do. However you've answered my question, in that the property in the data class has to be of type `State`/`MutableState`